# Space of path is relatively compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $x\in X.$ The path space $$T_{x}(X) = \{\sigma\in C°([0,1], X):\sigma(0)= x = \sigma(1)\}$$ from $x$ to $x$ is relatively compact on $C°([0,1], X)$ if and only if constant path from $x$ to $x$ is the unique path in $T_{x}(X).$
Here $C°([0,1], X)$ is the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $X.$

I am not sure how to prove this; Arzela-Ascoli theorem implies that if $T_{x}(X)$ is relatively compact then is equicontinuos and the sets $\{\sigma(t): \sigma\in T_{x}(X)\}$ are relatively compact for each $t,$ but I cannot see how this implies the constant mapping is the unique in such set.

The other implication follows because a point is always a compact set.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: I don't think you can apply Arzela-Ascoli theorem.  This theorem is regarding subsets of $C(X,\Bbb R)$ where $X$ is compact Hausforff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\sigma \in T_x(X)$ be a nontrivial path. As $\sigma$ is nontrivial, there is some $y \neq x$ in its image $\sigma([0,1])$. Let $D = \operatorname{dist}(x,y) > 0$.

Now define

\begin{align*}
 \sigma_n(t) =
  \begin{cases}
   x        & \text{if } t \in [0,1] \setminus \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \\
   \sigma \left( (n^2 + n)(t-\frac{1}{n+1}) \right)        & \text{if } t \in \left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right)
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then $\sigma_n \in T_x(X)$.

For $n \neq m$ we have $y \in \sigma_n([\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}])$ and $\sigma_m \restriction [\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}] = x$, hence:

$$||\sigma_n - \sigma_m|| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \operatorname{dist} (\sigma_n(t),\sigma_m(t)) \geq \sup_{t \in [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]} \operatorname{dist} (\sigma_n(t),\sigma_m(t)) \geq \operatorname{dist}(y,x) = D.$$

We proved that the set $\{\sigma_n; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq T_x(X)$ is $D$-isolated and $T_x(X)$ cannot be relatively compact.

Comment: Thanks @KeeperOfSecrets. That was so helpful.